# Cannot travel for second interview for post-doctorate position due to visa issues, will it reflect badly on me?

Tags: research-process, postdocs, interview

I am a PhD student from India.
I have been called for a personal second round interview for a post-doc position in the Netherlands just a few days ago. The call for the second interview is due this month (March). I may not be able to travel there due to visa issues (short-notice period). After talking to their HR, they are given me an option for an online presentation. I am worried whether it is going to reflect negatively on me some sort of disadvantage in the selection process.

Thanks!

Comment: The modality you will give the talk will not affect you, it was not going to affect your rating before COVID, it is not going to affect it after 2 years of lockdowns/home office etcetc.
However, *you* have a disadvantage: you cannot properly evaluate the "mood" of the department and of your potential colleagues. Interviews are a mutual evaluations, do not focus too much on yourself, focus on them.

Comment: Thank you for your honest feedback.

Comment: Make sure that your visa problem won't prevent you from going to the Netherlands to take up the postdoc position if it's offered to you. And then make sure that the interviewers know that.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes true that, its hard to get visa when the days are numbered (15 days). But if offered a position I will have time to apply in advance. But thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

A virtually-presented talk can be as efficient as a personally-presented one since your material can be delivered in both way with the same quality. Your audience also interact with you about what you present just like you are there. On their end, they would definitely understand the situation especially when the pandemic is still there. So, I don't see any drawback to deliver an online presentation.

However, a personal visit may provide you some unique opportunities that are almost tough (if not impossible) to reach via an online talk. For example, you and your potential PI and the remainder of colleagues may better know each other via direct socialization. As well, if your field is technical or lab-based, you may have the opportunity to visit their available research infrastructure to potentially provide your feedback about their suitability and your potential needs for your project.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I too am trying my best to get a visa.